# How to get 64bit system folder in a 32bit application?

Tags: windows, winapi, 32bit-64bit, special-folders, known-folders

In a 32bit application, I have to copy a file to the 64bit system folder
(`C:\Windows\System32\` instead of `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\`)

For this, I tried to get the folder using the WinAPI function [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with parameter [FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#FOLDERID_PROGRAMFILESX64) (GUID: 6D809377-6AF0-444b-8957-A3773F02200E).

But unfortunately, this is not allowed (as mentioned in the remarks section) and the function result correctly is 'file not found'.

**Is there a way to accomplish this?**

Comment: You're better off making your 32-bit program launch a separate 64-bit program that copies the files. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/22/9244582.aspx

Comment: Solve the problem by avoiding it. The problem vanishes when you obey the rules and don't modify the system directory.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Well my job is to install a DLL in both 32bit and 64bit versions to the system...

Comment: Unless you work for the Microsoft Windows team, it's against the platform rules to install to system directories. Obviously you can elect to ignore the rules, I'm just letting you know that you are breaking rules.

Comment: OK, so I missed something. What are the rules when I have to install a commonly used DLL (no assembly)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are requesting the **PROGRAM FILES** folder, not the **SYSTEM** folder.  Look at `FOLDERID_System` and `FOLDERID_SystemX86` instead.

Alternatively, use `FOLDERID_Windows` to get the Windows installation folder, and then append the special `SysNative` alias to the end of it, let the File System Redirector locate the actual folder for you, per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx):

> 32-bit applications can access the **native system directory** by substituting **%windir%\Sysnative** for %windir%\System32. **WOW64 recognizes Sysnative as a special alias used to indicate that the file system should not redirect the access.** This mechanism is flexible and easy to use, therefore, **it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file system redirection.** Note that 64-bit applications cannot use the Sysnative alias as it is a virtual directory not a real one.

Answer (score 4):

I'm confused why you would try `FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64` when you say you want the System32 folder, since the former would (if it worked) give you the **Program Files** folder. For the **System32** folder, you want the [`GetSystemDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724373(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

You can use the catchily-named [`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743(v=vs.85).aspx) function to disable WOW64 redirection, which allow your 32-bit app to actually access the 64 bit system folder. Then use [`Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365745(v=vs.85).aspx) to restore the redirection once you're done.

Also note that it's not actually recommended to store your own files in the System folder any more (and hasn't been for quite some time), as this note in the docs for `GetSystemDirectory` says:

> Applications should not create files in the system directory. If the
>   user is running a shared version of the operating system, the
>   application does not have write access to the system directory.

Comment: The application helps to install both variants (32 and 64 bit) of a DLL. Therefore I need both system folders *explicitly*.

Comment: For a 32-bit app the path to both 32 and 64 bit system folders is (e.g.) **C:\Windows\System32** - it's Wow64 filesystem redirection that determines which folder you end up accessing.

Comment: So switching the filesystem redirection on and off is the only way to target the correct folder - Is that what you're telling me?

Comment: It's not the only way to target it but I don't think there's a way to actually get the path to the 32 bit folder other than just assuming it's called SysWOW64 and is a sibling of System32. Whereas using the redirection trick you don't need to worry about where it's actually located.

Comment: OK I see. This assumes that my application is 32 bit. The best case would be that it is ensured to target System32 and SysWOW64, no matter if my application is 32 or 64 bit. If I have a 64 application, I could use the FOLDERID_??? then.

Comment: Why you shouldn't use `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` to solve a local problem and what you should use instead: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/21/10404021.aspx